# Sharing text through XBee on Arduino

Tags: xbee

How do I share text through an [XBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee) module?

I tried, but instead of a word, I am getting some numbers every time. I want to exchange text data from both sides. I am using an Arduino for communication. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please post your code?

Comment: Hi Tushar, you could accept the answer posted if it helped you out, unless you want to keep the question open for further discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I've been through a similar problem and was able to work around it. I assume you're using a MEGA 2560 and have a set of XBEE modules connected to two computers through the SPARKFUN XBEE USB explorer. 
I've included my code that you can upload to both of the XBEEs and use them as a simple walkie-talkie pair. The program is meant to read an entire incoming word/string terminated with a defined character.

```
 //xbee walkie-talkies 
#define EndOfInput '@'//define a terminating character
void setup() {

  Serial1.begin(9600); //serial thru pin 19
  Serial.begin(9600); //Serial monitor

}
String incomingWord=""; //initialize to NULL
char input; //to read the incoming character
void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()>0) {
    // send out whatever is typed at the serial
    //monitor thru the XBEE
    Serial1.write(Serial.read());  
  }
  //read the entire incoming word
  while(Serial1.available()>0){
    input = Serial1.read();
    if (input != EndOfInput) incomingWord+=input;
    else break;
  }
  //print out the word received on the serial monitor
  Serial.println(incomingWord);
  incomingWord = ""; //reset the string
}
```

It should be pretty self-explanatory.